# Infinite loop when using while loop and replace string with Swift

Tags: string, swift, replace

I need to write an script to replace string until nothing match.
However it didn't work.
Here is my script:

```
var datastring = NSString(data: data, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
while((datastring?.containsString(",,")) != nil)
{
   datastring = datastring!.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString(",,", withString: ",")
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You current code simply check whether `containsString` returns value or `nil`. Basically it same as checking whether `datastring` is `nil` or not. Whenever its not `nil` the infinite loop is started.

Simplified and fixe code:

```
while datastring?.containsString(",,") == true {
    datastring = datastring?.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString(",,", withString: ",")
}
```

Comment: Your fixed code didn't work. I have tried it before but xcode required me to add `!= nil` into my code. That was weird because this logic code did work in PHP because datastring variable have been changing all the times.

Comment: @TomSawyer sorry had bug in my code. Try the fixed version.

Answer (score 0):

Does *the string contains ",,"* → no (i.e. false). False is different of nil. That's why you are falling in an infinite loop.

You might need a `if` test if you want. Or, you could directly use the `stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString` method.

```
var str = "Hello,, playground,, this is a test string."
str = str.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString(",,", withString: ",")
println(str) // Hello, playground, this is a test string.
```

It will replaces all occurence**s**.

**Edit with loop :**

```
var str : NSString = "Hello,,, playground,,,,,, this is ,,,,a test string."

while (str.containsString(",,") == true) {
    str = str.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString(",,", withString: ",")
} // 3 times

println(str) // Hello, playground, this is a test string.
```

Demonstration : http://swiftstub.com/22979236/

Comment: This will leave ",,," to ",,". But then again I am not sure about the OP requirements.

Comment: your code won't work because it only replace `,,` for one time only. you'll need a loop to match and replace all matched strings

Comment: Your specification didn't mention that your string might include more than two commas. I edit to take that in consideration.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to check both use this:

```
while  (datastring != nul) && (datastring.containsString(",,")) {
    datastring = datastring.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString(",,", withString: ",")
}
```

It will first check if it is not nil and then if it contains selected string (in this case, that string is ",,"). I belive if your object is nil and you first check if it contains some string, it will crash your app.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know whether it's because you have an NSString and the replace method returns a String (maybe it sends the bridging between String and NSString a bit haywire?), but you can make this work in the following way:

```
let datastring = "Hello,, Hello,,,"
let data = datastring.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)
var str = NSString(data: data!, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding) as! String
while str.rangeOfString(",,") != nil
{
    str = str.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString(",,", withString: ",")
}
str // Hello, Hello,
```

which ensures we're firmly in the territory of String and use only String methods not NSString methods.

The following also works if you want to stay with NSString:

```
let datastring = "Hello,,,,,, Hello,,,,,,,"
let data = datastring.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)
var str:NSString = NSString(data: data!, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)!
while str.containsString(",,") {
    str = str.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString(",,", withString: ",")
}
str // "Hello, Hello,"
```

It means you get completely away from optionals, which is what the NSString initializer returns but if you search StackOverflow there are warnings about containsString not being in the documentation and not being included until iOS8 (which seems [confirmed here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/releasenotes/General/iOS80APIDiffs/frameworks/Foundation.html)), i.e. not working with iOS7. I haven't looked any deeper at this but it's something worth exploring if you're supporting iOS7.

Note: I've only used a force cast to String (and a forced unwrapping of data) for brevity, IRL you'd test these to make sure neither returned nil.